# Lose some data while multiple adding rows to the bottom of Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have a google form. Responses from the form are going to the connected table.
A also have Google Script' `onSubmitForm` trigger, which take new responses and put some of them (which satisfy some requirements) into another table.

So, my script put responses into bottom of my table `(lastRow+1)`index.

The problem is when my form are being submitted by severals people at the same time.
I think this is happening because script executes at the same time, so `(lastRow+1)`index can be the same for severals executing scripts. So simultaneously executing scripts rewrite some of the rows. And some data is lost.

The question is how to manage this situation? How to add all responses (which should be added) and not losing some of them?

A have 2 implementation of appending data.
First:

```
// Добавляет нового курьера вниз таблицы 
function addCourierTnTheBottom(response) {
  var destinationSpreadsheetID = '[table ID]';
  var destinationRangeName = 'Курьеры!A1:O';
  var destinationValues = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(destinationSpreadsheetID, destinationRangeName).values;
  var valueInputOption = "RAW"
  var lastDestinationRow = destinationValues.length
  var valueRanges = []

  // Формируем данные
  var edit_date_formatted = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Europe/Moscow',  "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var created_date = response[0];
  var full_name = response[1];
  var work_phone = response[2];
  var contact_phone = response[3];
  var citizenship = response[4];
  var age = response[5];
  var city = response[6];
  var source = response[7];
  var interview_date = response[8];
  var status = "Новый. Тестирование";
  var test_form_submitted_status = "Не отправлено";

  // отправка формы на тестирование
  var result = submitFormOnTest(response);
  if (result) { test_form_submitted_status = "Успешно отправлена"; }

  var rangeName = getRangeForRow(lastDestinationRow, 'A', 'O');
  var values = [city, created_date, edit_date_formatted, full_name, work_phone, contact_phone, citizenship, source, interview_date, status, "","","","",test_form_submitted_status];

  // Отправляем данные в таблицу
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange()
  valueRange.values = [values]
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, destinationSpreadsheetID, rangeName, { valueInputOption: valueInputOption });
  Logger.log(result)

  // Дополнительная функция
  function getRangeForRow(rowNumber, columnFirst, columnLast) {
    return 'Курьеры!' + columnFirst + (rowNumber+1) + ':' + columnLast + (rowNumber+1)
  }
}
```

The second one:

```
function addNewCourierToTheBottom2(response) {

  // Формируем данные
  var edit_date_formatted = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Europe/Moscow',  "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var created_date = response[0];
  var full_name = response[1];
  var work_phone = response[2];
  var contact_phone = response[3];
  var citizenship = response[4];
  var age = response[5];
  var city = response[6];
  var source = response[7];
  var interview_date = response[8];
  var status = "Новый. Тестирование";
  var test_form_submitted_status = "Не отправлено";

  // отправка формы на тестирование
  var result = submitFormOnTest(response);
  if (result) { test_form_submitted_status = "Успешно отправлена"; }

  var values = [city, created_date, edit_date_formatted, full_name, work_phone, contact_phone, citizenship, source, interview_date, status, "","","","",test_form_submitted_status];

  // Заносим все после последней строки таблицы
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[table ID]")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Курьеры")
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 15).setValues([values]); 
}
```

The both have this issue. I've no idea how to fix it. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use lastRow()  get the data you need from the event object.  You can even get the row number from the range.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit

Comment: Event object is related to form's table (where automatically responses fall in). My script take every response and put it to another (unrelated to form) table. So form's table stores all responses, while my another table stores only some of them with some additional data.

Comment: So I can't use event object to get amount of rows of that table

Comment: Well I would rethink that and try to avoid having to be concerned with passed entries because no matter what you do sooner or later your going to run out of time because there is too many responses in the linked sheet.  I don't like using this for this purpose but you might try [lock service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock).

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND

### Instead of copying the data `onFormSubmit` do it on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

- Implement and additional column with checkboxes
- Each time the function will run on trigger, it shall

  - find all the rows where the checkbox is not checked yet
  - copy those rows
  - check the corresponding checkboxes, so next time the function is run the same rows won't get copied again

Instead of checkboxes you can alternatively e.g. store the last copied row in [Scriptproperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) and start copying on next trigger from this row